# Honeybadger for Ruby is not filtering attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Honeybadger is set up on my Rails app, and some errors continue to report information that was added to the filter_keys list in `config/honeybadger.yml`. These fields have also been added to `/config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb`.

They appear in the Backtrace under Nested Exceptions. It looks like this, though I've anonymized it:

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry 'test@email.com' for key 'index_users_on_email': INSERT INTO `users` (`encrypted_password`, `confirmed_at`, `authentication_token`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `locale`, `provider`, `uid`, `app`, `email`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `location`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `region`, `state`, `password_set_at`) VALUES ([password shown but redadcted], '2023-03-23 16:58:08', '[authentication_token shown]', '2023-03-23 16:58:08', '2023-03-23 16:58:08', 'en', [provider], [uid], [app], 'test@email.com', 'Jane', 'Doe', [city, state], []lat, [long], [region], [state], '2023-03-23 16:58:08')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the info you want to suppress is not in the params or session hash, but is in the message of an exception. Filtering hash keys won’t work in this case; instead, you can use the [before_notify](https://docs.honeybadger.io/lib/ruby/getting-started/customizing-error-grouping/) callback to manually filter out the sensitive data from the exception message. Please feel free to [open a issue](https://github.com/honeybadger-io/honeybadger-ruby/issues/new) on our gem repo if you’d like to ask us to investigate an alternative solution in the gem.